# How to create straight edges at specific corners using graphviz

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

I have the below code to create a simple flow using graphviz to be visualized in jupyter notebook

```
# Create Digraph object
dot = Digraph()

# Add nodes 
dot.node('1', shape='box')
dot.node('2', shape='rectangle')
dot.node('3', shape='parallelogram')
dot.node('4', shape='diamond')
dot.node('5', shape='box')

# Add edge between nodes
dot.edges(['12', '23', '34', '42', '45' ])

# Visualize the graph
dot
```

How to make an edge from decision box right corner to box 2 a straight line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls define edges and `tailport='e', headport='e'` helps to define the right side (e=east). `tailport: from where, headport: to where.`

Code:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

dot = Digraph(graph_attr={'splines': 'ortho'})

dot.node('1', shape='box')
dot.node('2', shape='rectangle')
dot.node('3', shape='parallelogram')
dot.node('4', shape='diamond')
dot.node('5', shape='box')

dot.edge('1', '2')
dot.edge('2', '3')
dot.edge('3', '4')
dot.edge('4', '2', tailport='e', headport='e', constraint='false')
dot.edge('4', '5')

dot
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, can the edge 42 be a straight line having corners?

Comment: @newstudent I updated it, straight lines with corners.

Answer (score 2):

No idea of how to do it in Python, but the clue is to use

- compass points, here `:se`
- spline type, here `splines=ortho`

```
digraph G {
splines=ortho
1 [shape=box]
2 [shape="rectangle"]


  "1":se -> "2"

}
```

feeding this in http://www.webgraphviz.com/ result in:

[image]